# How add custom field (Product Sku) in Order export CSV magento2.2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order, importexport, magento2.2

I need to export my orders to csv. I need two fields product sku and qty.

```
sales > Order > export
```

Any way to add Product SKU's as comma separated or any extension that can do it?
[image]

Comment: I have extension let me know anyone needs it.

Comment: Can you able to export SKU in your CSV file? I faced with same scenario.

Comment: yes I purchased extension.

Comment: @Magento2 Devloper  What's the extension please?

Comment: send me a mail on apmagento92@gmail.com